# docker error with python application (user interactive mode ? )

Tags: python, docker

Enter the text:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "caesarCipher.py", line 16, in <module>
    text=input("Enter the text: ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

how can I fix this ? Thank you

Comment: What is the command you are using to run the container?

Comment: docker run cipher       #where cipher is the name of the image

Comment: Inside docker you should not get data from terminal. You should create rest api or any other kind of service.

Comment: Make sure the container is run with the `-ti` arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run your container with the `-it` flags (interactive terminal). This will allow you to interact with the process running inside the container.

For example:

*foo.py*

```
x = input('Enter some input: ')
print(x)
```

*Dockerfile*

```
from python

COPY foo.py .

ENTRYPOINT python foo.py
```

*Usage*

```
$ docker build . -t foo
$ docker run -it foo
Enter some input: foo
foo
$
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem that you defined your script to be the entrypoint of your container. Inside the script the [input function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) expects to have either a tty or a stream.

Running the script inside the container like this will do the trick:

```sh
docker run -it your_docker_container /path/to/your/script.py
```